# How to get sourcelines for lambda functions used as function arguments

Tags: python

I am working with a function that takes lambda functions as arguments. I want to be able to get the sourcelines for each lambda function. I have been trying to do this using the inspect module, but am struggling to get a solution.

The code below illustrates the problem:

```
import inspect
def foo(**kwargs):
    return inspect.getsourcelines(kwargs["new"])
foo(new  = 
    lambda x: 
    x.var + 1,
    old  =  lambda  x: x.var)
```

It returns "(['    lambda x: \n'], 6)".  but what I really want is "lambda x: x.var +1".

Alternatively I want an easy way to extract the function call at the start of foo, which in this case would give `foo(new  = lambda x: x.var + 1, old  =  lambda  x: x.var)".

The use case here is where I need to translate the lambda function into a call for a programming language other than Python. So essentially I need to parse the function args.

Comment: `([' lambda x: x.var + 1,\n'], 6)[0][0]` will give you `"lambda x: x.var +1"`

Comment: Is there any reason why ``foo`` does not directly take the appropriate source, e.g. ``foo(new="x: x.var + 1", old="x: x.var")`` or similar? How should ``foo`` deal with functions supplied by other means that lambda expressions, e.g. via name?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thats a typo on the askers part, `inspect.getsourcelines` does not return a string

Comment: Apologies. The example was not quite right. Now fixed. The main issue is that when the `foo` call is split over multiple lines inspect.getsourcelines only picks up one line